# Divisible Numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print out a statement from 1-50 and if it is divisible by 10, then it prints out "Hello!", and it moves on. I have this part so far:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i+=1) {
console.log(i);
if {
```

Example:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,Hello!,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,Hello!,21...

Comment: I'm guessing this is for a school assignment?  Research "Javascript Modulus".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; ++i) console.log(i % 10 === 0 ? 'Hello!' : i);
```

[The `%` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) gets the remainder of dividing by 10 - if it is `0`, then it's directly divisible by 10.

For example, see this:

```
11 % 10; // 1, not divisible by 10
200 % 10; // 0, divisible by 10
9999999 % 10; // 9, not divisible by 10
```

[The conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) has the following syntax:

```
condition ? x : y
```

It returns the first value (`x`) if true, and the second value (`y`) if false. Our condition is whether the remainder of the number when dividing it by 10 is 0 (exactly divisible).  If that's the case, it will pass `'Hello!'` to the `console.log` function, otherwise it will pass the number itself. It's similar to how an if-else works, but it's an expression, not a statement. For example, see this:

```
console.log(true ? 1 : 0); // 1
console.log(1 ? 'true :)' : 'false :('); // true :)
console.log(null ? NaN : -Infinity); // -Infinity
```

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me. But if you have time, do you think you can explain to me why you make "it ===0 ? "? I don't understand what the ? does

Comment: @user3003923: updated my answer to explain how it works.

Comment: Ok, thank you! And do you know how I can make this viewable in HTML? or would it be better to code this in HTML?

Comment: @user3003923: try searching for how to display JavaScript variables in HTML on Google - there are numerous results from Stack Overflow on there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i+=1) {
    if { i%10 == 0 ) console.log( "hello" );
else console.log(i);
    }
```

Comment: why the negative vote?

Comment: I'd guess that OP asked for 1-50. Your loop runs from 1 to 100.

Comment: @MikeW made the change now

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    if(i%10 === 0) {
     console.log('hello');   
    } else {
     console.log(i);   
    }
}
```

Please go through js [operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_operators.htm)

Comment: @Downvoter pls let me know the mistake here .. such tat I can correct from next time.